# How to display and update value in SelectField in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-dropdown-tree-select

There are two select fields, `Language` and `Currency`. I am getting values dynamically showing in both fields, but now I have to change drop down value and op press on button I am calling Onclick fucntion and updating to server .

1. If not changing cvalue in preferredLanguage and updating its showing undefined
2. preferredCurrency - if am using below code for this is  giving boolean value.

Please review my code and correct it .

I have to display data dynamically in both selectfield and after changing the value in selectfield and update it should updated current selected value .

```
     this.state = {  languageAndCurrecny:{
            preferredLanguage: navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].billingPreferenceDetails.presentationLanguageCode,
          },
            currencyChangedValue:{
        preferredCurrency: navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].billingPreferenceDetails.preferedCurrencyCode,
      }

      this.handleChangeCurrency=this.handleChangeCurrency.bind(this);
}

OnButtonClick = async (preferredLanguage, preferredCurrency) => {
    const { OnButtonClick } = this.props;
    await OnButtonClick(preferredLanguage, preferredCurrency);

    this.setState({
          preferredCurrency:'',
          preferredLanguage:'',
    })
}

languageChanged = (key, val) => {
    this.handleChange({ field: "preferredLanguage" }, val);
};

handleChange = (props, e) => {
    let tempObj = this.state.languageAndCurrecny;
    tempObj[props.field] = e;
    this.setState({ preferredLanguage: tempObj });
  };

  currencyChanged = (key, val) => {
    this.handleChangeCurrency({ field: "preferredCurrency" }, val);
  };

  handleChangeCurrency = (props, e) => {
    let tempObj = this.state.currencyChangedValue;
    tempObj[props.field] = e;
    this.setState({ preferredCurrency: tempObj });
  };
      render (
      let {languageAndCurrecny,currencyChangedValue} = this.state;
      const { navigation, clmmasterData } = this.props;
      const { masterData, language } = clmmasterData;
      let currencyData=[];
        masterData.preferredCurrency.map(({ code: value, name: label }) => {
          currencyData.push({ value, label });
        });

        let languageData=[];
        masterData.language.map(({ code: value, name: label }) => {
          languageData.push({ value, label });
        });
        return (

    <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
                    <Form style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                      <SelectField
                        label="Presentation Language"
                        node="presentationLanguage"
                        options={languageData}
                        value={languageAndCurrency.preferredLanguage}
                        onChange={this.languageChanged}
                        that={this}
                        setIcon={true}
                        img="LANGUAGE"
                      />

                      <SelectField
                        label="Preferred Currency"
                        options={currencyData}
                        value={preferredCurrency}
                        node="preferredCurrency"
                        onChange={this.handleChangeCurrency}
                        that={this}
                        setIcon={true}
                        img="CURRENCY"
                      />

                      <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
                        <PrimaryBtn label={'submit'} disabled={false} onPress={()=> this.OnButtonClick(this.state.preferredLanguage,this.state.preferredCurrency,)}/>
                      </View>
```

Thanks .. Please help

Answer (score 0):

new answer:

`onChange` returns a value which contain new selected value.

Use these 2 function as below

```
 languageChanged = (key, val) => {
    let languageAndCurrecny.preferredLanguage = val
    this.setState({ languageAndCurrecny: languageAndCurrecny})
};
```

handleChangeCurrency(value){

```
this.setState({
    preferredCurrency: value
})}
```

Old answer just add this in render method, you just missed `preferredCurrency`:

```
let { languageAndCurrecny, preferredCurrency } = this.state;
```

Comment: But this I can set value in Value props , but..let me update my question

Comment: Thanks for your time , I have updated my question please see.

Comment: languageAndCurrecny.prefferedLanguage is trowing, could you pelase update in my question